# How to limt angularjs ng-repeat array object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have to limit Angularjs array object. If it is array at that I am using `limitTo` filter, it was working

But in this case I have to limit my object array.

I need to limit first to objects only

Here my html code :

```
<md-select required name="filterType"
               ng-model="filter.type" aria-label="{{ 'alias.filter-type' | translate }}">
    <md-option ng-value="type.value" ng-repeat="type in aliasFilterTypes |limitTo:3" >

        {{type.name | translate}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

my array object is :

```
{
    "singleEntity": {
        "value":"singleEntity",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-single-entity"
    },
    "entityList":{
         "value":"entityList",
         "name":"alias.filter-type-entity-list"
    },
    "entityName":{
        "value":"entityName",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-entity-name"
    },
    "stateEntity":{
        "value":"stateEntity",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-state-entity"
    },
    "assetType":{
        "value":"assetType",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-asset-type"
    },
    "deviceType":{
        "value":"deviceType",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-device-type"
    },
    "relationsQuery":{
        "value":"relationsQuery",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-relations-query"
    },
    "assetSearchQuery":{
        "value":"assetSearchQuery",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-asset-search-query"
    },
    "deviceSearchQuery":{
        "value":"deviceSearchQuery",
        "name":"alias.filter-type-device-search-query"
    }
}
```

Comment: you may can do something like : `ng-repeat="type in aliasFilterTypes.slice(0,3)" ` ?

Comment: thank you for your respond. but is not working, data is not displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$index` with `ng-if`

```
<md-select required name="filterType" ng-model="filter.type" aria-label="{{ 'alias.filter-type' | translate }}">
    <md-option ng-value="type.value" ng-repeat="type in aliasFilterTypes" ng-if="$index < 2">

        {{type.name | translate}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Comment: just change < 2

Answer (score 1):

`limitTo` filter checks for the value of the key so it's not working on your case.

You should use `$index` and add `ng-if` condition to your `ng-repeat`ed element. Try;

```
ng-repeat="type in aliasFilterTypes" ng-if="$index < 3"
```